# How can I add my own images to silicone beads?

Tags: beads

I would like to make my friends, who own a clothing boutique, some custom silicone wristlets. I can’t find exactly what I’m looking for and would love to add their name or something or the such to an individual bead in said wristlet. I’ve researched and researched and have come up with zero ideas on how to do that. Would hydrodipping work? Like print tiny images from a printer onto hydro paper and dip each individual bead? I’m not a business and only want to make this special gift for two special ladies. Anybody know how I could accomplish this or have any ideas I could try?